# Proving the basis formulation of the topology of compact convergence

Tags: general-topology

**Definition.**

Let $(Y,d)$ be a metric space; let $X$ be a topological space. Given an element $f$ of $Y^X$, a compact subspace $C$ of $X$, and a number $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $B_C(f,\epsilon)$ denote the set of all those elements $g$ of $Y^X$ for which sup{$d(f(x),g(x))|x \in C$} $\lt \epsilon$.

This is the definition from Munkres' Topology. My question is, why do the sets $B_C(f,\epsilon)$ form a basis for a topology on $Y^X$? For this, I need to check two conditions: the fact that there is a basis element for every point in the set is obvious, however, the second one is unclear. Munkres says that the crucial step is to note that if $g \in B_C(f,\epsilon)$, then for $\delta = \epsilon$ $-$  sup{$d(f(x),g(x))|x \in C$}, we have $B_C(g,\delta) \subset B_C(f,\epsilon)$.

This part is clear to me, however, since the basis elements is over all compact subsets of $X$, and we don't have the guarantee that $X$ is Hausdorff, the intersection of two compact sets may be noncompact. Then, how do we show that given $h \in B_C(g,\delta_1) \cap B_K(f,\delta_2)$, where $C, K$ are compact subsets of $X$, there is a basis element containing $h$ contained in the following intersection? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't need that the intersection of two (quasi)compact subsets of $X$ is again compact, we need that the *union* of two compact subsets $C,K$ of $X$ is compact. That is the case in all topological spaces.

Then we let

$$\delta = \min \left\{ \delta_1 - \sup \{d(h(x),g(x)) : x \in C\},\; \delta_2 - \sup \{d(h(x),f(x)) : x \in K\}\right\}$$

and consider $B_{C\cup K}(h,\delta)$.